# How to make sure that the website remembers the user's theme on reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm creating this ToDo App using MongoDB, EJS and Node JS. The issue I face is the theme changer button that I have included. When ever I press it, everything changes colors as it should. But due to the fact that whenever a new item is added to the database my page reloads causing the theme to go back to default colors. Is there a way to make the website remember the user selection? Here's my code:

JS SECTION

```
const theme_btn = document.getElementById("theme");

const h1_tag = document.querySelector(".title");
const drag_drop_tag = document.querySelector(".drag_drop");

const input_box_tag = document.querySelector(".user_input_box");
const check_mark_tag = document.querySelectorAll(".check_mark");
const userInput_form_tag = document.querySelector(".userInput_form input");

const list_display_tag = document.querySelector(".list_display");
const item_display_tag = document.querySelectorAll(".item_display");
const item_content_tag = document.querySelectorAll(".item_content");

const statues_tag = document.querySelector(".statues");

theme_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(theme_btn.src.includes("sun") === true) {
        theme_btn.src = "../images/icon-moon.svg"

        document.body.classList.add("light_body");  
        h1_tag.classList.add("light_header");   
        drag_drop_tag.classList.add("light_drag-drop"); 
        
        input_box_tag.classList.add("light_input_box"); 
        check_mark_tag.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.add("light_check_mark"); 
        })
        userInput_form_tag.classList.add("light_userInput_form"); 

        list_display_tag.classList.add("light_list_display"); 
        item_display_tag.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.add("light_item_display"); 
        })
        item_content_tag.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.add("light_item_content"); 
        })
        
        statues_tag.classList.add("light_statues"); 
        
    } else if(theme_btn.src.includes("moon") === true) {
        theme_btn.src = "../images/icon-sun.svg"

        document.body.classList.remove("light_body"); 
        h1_tag.classList.remove("light_header");   
        drag_drop_tag.classList.remove("light_drag-drop");  

        input_box_tag.classList.remove("light_input_box"); 
        check_mark_tag.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove("light_check_mark"); 
        }) 
        userInput_form_tag.classList.remove("light_userInput_form"); 

        list_display_tag.classList.remove("light_list_display"); 
        item_display_tag.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove("light_item_display"); 
        })
        item_content_tag.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove("light_item_content"); 
        }) 

        statues_tag.classList.remove("light_statues"); 
    }
})
```

Live Link: https://todo-remainder-app.herokuapp.com/
Github Link: https://github.com/StormKing969/ToDo-App

Thank You for your help

Comment: Save the theme state in localStorage or a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible options

1. Store the theme in local storage or cookie as @mr-polywhirl suggested. Whenever your page loads, check localstorage/cookie to see if the value exists.
2. Change your design so that adding a new item to the database is an asynchronous request (which means the page isn't reloaded)